# why H2 database append prefix before my value

Tags: sql, insert, h2, h2db

I have a table in H2 database. 
In this table there are 2 columns like below:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (id bigserial NOT NULL,lffo_file text);
```

`id   |  value
--------------` 
I execute this query :

```
 INSERT INTO mytable (value , id) VALUES ( '/resource/public/1555687199892.js','1555684557909')
```

After that when I execute this query:

```
select * from my table
```

It shows me :

```
id              |      value
-----------------------------------------
1555684557909   |  clob4: '/resource/public/1555687199892.js'
```

Why does H2 append this prefix << clob4: >> ?

(I just know ,clob is data type for huge varchar)

Comment: Do you use any GUI?

Comment: no pavel , just create statement and execute query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a while

H2 database automaticly consider Text as clob datatype 
and when you create a table with Text column it was changed to clob

and then: 
when you insert a text value it persist a text like KVP format : 
suppose you inserted 'Alex' and then 'Beti' in the value column

so it persist like below:

`value
clob0 : 'Alex'
clob1 : 'Beti'`

as you see in the kvp, key is 'clobe' + counter

so i changed text type to varchar (without size) and depend on postgresql documentation there is no difference between varchar and text performance

all of this is what i saw and if there is a better answer please share it, thanks